# HQL how to check if an object exists within a collection which is entered from outside?

Tags: hibernate, hql, jpql

I have the following:

```
   ***Homework.class***
    id;
    name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE,
                CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE })
        @JoinColumn(name = "lesson_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    Lesson lesson;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "studentHomeworks", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<User> homeworkStudents;

    ***Lesson.class***
    id;
    etc;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "lesson", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Homework> lessonHomeworks;
        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "studentLessons", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<User> lessonStudents;

    ***User.class***
    id;
    etc.;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE,
                CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE })
        @JoinTable(name = "oys_lesson_student", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "uq_student_lesson", columnNames = {
                "student_id", "lesson_id" }), joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "lesson_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private Set<Lesson> studentLessons;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @JoinTable(name = "oys_student_homework", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "uq_student_homework", columnNames = {
            "student_id", "homework_id" }), joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "homework_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
private Set<Homework> studentHomeworks;
```

And I tried something like this:

```
query = "select h from Homework h where h.stop_time > :now and h.lesson in elements(:lessons)"
```

doesn't work set parameter function in elements keyword.So How can I do that?I want to get homeworks for user with registered lessons.I entered the registered lessons from outside.how to check if an object(lesson object from Homework) exists within a collection(lessons that the user is registered) which is entered from outside?

Comment: What is entered? What is the type of the `lessons` parameter? You probably want it to be a Set<Long> (Long being the type of the ID of Lesson), and use `and h.lesson.id in :lessons`

Comment: :lessons parameter is Set<Lesson> studentLessons.İm looking student lessons if homework's Lesson exists in studentLessons,return true

Comment: which method should I use instead of elements()?

Comment: AFAIK, `h.lesson in :lessons` should work. Otherwise, use what I advised in my first comment.